# My 1999 Toyota Sienna takes time to start and when I press accelerator it goes off

Tags: electrical, sienna

My 1999 Toyota Sienna will take time to start when it cools and when it eventually start and I want to raise it by pressing the accelerator, it goes off and I have to restart it again.

And again if I am driving and I parked for 2 minutes without putting it off and I put in drive again, it will go off and I will need to restart it.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I've edited your question as while it's *possible* you've got a MY2019 Sienna I think it's probably more likely that the 1999 year listed in the title was more accurate. Hopefully I got that one right but if not feel free to rollback my edit.

Comment: Is there a check engine light on and if so do you know what it is for?

Comment: When you say start I assume that the starter is turning the engine over, but the engine won't start?

Answer (score 0):

Given the trouble starting it I'd be inclined to say it's a bad ignition coil.

Another possibility is the torque converter locking up (surprisingly common on 90's Toyota auto boxes)...but that wouldn't explain the starting troubles.

Comment: If it's cranking, but not starting, a bad coil is a good candidate.  A good first step would be to see if you have a spark at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would check, clean or replace, the mass airflow sensor or map sensor. This is what tells the car how much load is on the engine if this value is wrong it can and will exhibit the symptoms you have. Moreover, it may not trip the engine light if the sensor is just out of spec and not burnt out. As this sensor is used to check values that naturally change quickly.

Answer (score -1):

welcome, when your car is cool you start it to go, so firstly you leave the for almost 5 minute in start position. Then you will go easily by pressing the accelerator, it can't goes off. 
but it doesn't go through this then the problem is in your car engine consumption of fuel. The fuel is not coming to engine properly. In the way of the fuel, there is some rubbish which can't leave the fuel to came to the engine properly. So when you press the accelerator, it goes off.
so kindly, check the transaction of the fuel of your car engine.